# An example of a bivariate pdf, where marginals are triangular distributions

Tags: copula, bivariate, triangular-distribution

What could be a form of 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)$$
where $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(x)$ both have the form of a triangular distribution with support $(0,1)$, but with different parameters that governs location of mode?

Some discussion on it could be found in

Eagleson, G.K., Lancaster, H.O.: The regression system of sums with random elements in common. Australian Journal of Statistics 9, 119–125 (1967)

and

Balakrishnan, N, Lai, Chin-Diew: Continuous Bivariate Distributions (2009)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nice way to do this is to use copulae.

In your case:

- let $X \sim \text{Triangular}(0,1)$ with pdf $f(x)$ and parameter $b$, and
- let $Y \sim \text{Triangular}(0,1)$ with pdf $g(y)$ and parameter $c$:

[image]

with cdf's $F(x)$ and $G(y)$:

[image]

... where I am using the `Prob` function (from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*) to automate the nitty-gritties of the cdf calculation.

Then, define a copula function, which is a function of the two cdf's $F$ and $G$ that creates a bivariate joint distribution function (cdf) from $F$ and $G$, such that the marginal pdf's of $X$ and $Y$ are still $f$ and $g$ respectively. Here, I use a Morgenstern copula with parameter $\alpha$ that induces correlation (there are many many other Copula functions available):

[image]

Let $h(x,y)$ denote the bivariate Triangular joint pdf obtained via a Morgenstern copula. Here we differentiate the Copula function (joint cdf) to derive the joint pdf $h(x,y)$:

[image]

The following diagram plots the joint pdf $h(x,y)$ when $b = \frac12$, $c = \frac34$ and $\alpha = 0$ (independent):

[image]

Here is the same plot when $\alpha = -1$:

[image]

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. I knew that I need to do copula and tried to do something myself but then I thought that I'm likely to make a mistake and decided to go with a uniform density for both RW

This stuff is so helpful. I'll use exactly this in the paper I'm doing. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Hey Wolfies, I can not replicate your results. For some reasons, Mathematica does not return Prob function properly... Any chance you could explain a little a tiny bit further, maybe you skipped something?  Also, I have the latest version, could there be some incompatibilities?

Comment: Nope, nothing works, embarrassing. Is there any chance you could post your *.nb? Is that something people do here?

Comment: @Sergey Note that the `Prob` function belongs to the _mathStatica_ package, which is an add-on to _Mathematica_.